# Java CookieManager or CookieHandler expire?

Tags: java, cookies, httpurlconnection

I make HTTP requests to site using the following:

//executed when calling for the first time to the server

```
static {
        cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);     
        CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager); 
}
```

and the following makes the actual call

```
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;

            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0");

//I added these 2 lines as a trial to fix this problem but failed           
            cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);     
            CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager); 

            conn.connect();         
            InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
...
```

The above works great for some time but at some point (don't know how much time exactly) the response I get says that my cookies are disabled and that I should enable them. Restarting the server makes it work again until it happens again and so on...

the cookieManager and cookieHandler expire at some point?
Am I missing something?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't control this on the CookieManager level but directly within the cookie itself. The [`HttpCookie`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html) has [`setMaxAge(long expiry)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html#setMaxAge-long-) sets the maximum age of the cookie in seconds.

As you can see at both the source code of HttpCookie, where is [`MAX_AGE_UNSPECIFIED`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/HttpCookie.java#HttpCookie.0MAX_AGE_UNSPECIFIED), and the [`getMaxAge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html#setMaxAge-long-) method documentation that the default value is set to `-1`.

> By default, -1 indicating the cookie will persist until browser shutdown.

[`setMaxAge(long expiry)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpCookie.html#setMaxAge-long-) states the following:

> A negative value means that the cookie is not stored persistently and will be deleted when the Web browser exits.

Comment: Thanks, as you can see, I don't send any actual cookie so how can I set the age? The purpose is just to enable the cookie mechanism as far as I understand from the message I get